# UIButton currentimage is not returning image when switching from background to foreground?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I am checking an image of button to get its state, like this:

```
if([syncBtn.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playbtn1.png"]])
{
  //Do something if play button
}
else if([syncBtn.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"syncbtn1.png"]])
{
  //Do something if sync button
}
else 
{
   //do something when no image on button
}
```

There is always an image on button either syncbtn1.png or playbtn1.png.

This above check is working fine but when I go to backgroud & then return to foreground then only its not able to check the button's current image from above method, its going in else condition.

What could be wrong?

Comment: The `UIImage`'s `isEqual ` is not performing image processing. So please change you logic for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are comparing the UIImage instances. They are cached by default, so you get the same instance most of the time. But after the app has been to the background, the cache is cleared and you get a new instance, what means it is not matching anymore.

Two options to fix it..

**Using your current way:**

1. Create your image instances only once and save them in a strong property.
2. Assign these images to your button and also check against these instances.

**Using button states:**

1. Set the `playbtn1.png` image for the `UIControlStateNormal`
2. Set the `syncbtn1.png` image for the `UIControlStateSelected`
3. Now just set and check for `syncBtn.selected` - the images will change automatically, if you change the selected flag.

Comment: Thanks Jaydee3. can you tell me how to save image instances only once and save then in a strong property? as you said in 1st solution

Comment: Thanks jaydee3. I saved it in the UIImage variable rather than fetching again from bundle. Thanks